# if inputbox.value1 ="0.00" then inputbox.text1 background-color '#595959'

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have an array of input fields in a "pair"

e.g.

value1 text1

value2 text2

value3 text3

value4 text4

How can I change the background-color of text1 if value1 = 0.00

Thanks in advance :)

```
        <div style="width: 30%; float:left;">
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value1" name="value1" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value2" name="value2" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value3" name="value3" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value4" name="value4" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value5" name="value5" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value6" name="value6" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value7" name="value7" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value8" name="value8" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value9" name="value9" value="0.00" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
    </div>      

    <div style="width: 70%; float:right;">
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text3" name="text3" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text4" name="text4" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text5" name="text5" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text6" name="text6" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text7" name="text7" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text8" name="text8" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text9" name="text9" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think that you need to clarify your question. Are you asking how to change the colour of the box **only** when `input == 0.00` OR are you enquiring how to interpolate between colours dependant on the input between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few suggestion here
1.Never mix your mark up with javascript. Consider adding/attaching events to a textbox or button at javascript end

Check the following code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sizebox").change(function(){
 
    var value=$(this).val();
  var idValue=$(this).data('value');
   
    var text=$("#text"+idValue);
    if(value==="0.00")
        text.addClass('red');
    else{
      text.removeClass('red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 30%; float:left;">
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value1" data-value="1" name="value1" value="0.00"  /><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value2" data-value="2" name="value2" value="0.00"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value3" data-value="3"  name="value3" value="0.00" /><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value4"  name="value4" value="0.00"  data-value="4"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value5" name="value5" value="0.00"  data-value="5"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value6" name="value6" value="0.00" data-value="6"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value7" name="value7" value="0.00" data-value="7"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value8" name="value8" value="0.00" data-value="8"/><br>
        <input class="sizebox" type="number" id="value9" name="value9" value="0.00" data-value="9"/>
  <br>
    </div>      

    <div style="width: 70%; float:right;">
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text3" name="text3" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text4" name="text4" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text5" name="text5" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text6" name="text6" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text7" name="text7" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text8" name="text8" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
        <input class="itembox" type="text" id="text9" name="text9" placeholder="item" list="itemlist" onchange="javascript:addNumbers()" onclick="this.select();"/><br>
    </div>
```

I have added a data-value attribute on the markup for value textboxes.In this i am just storing the numbers 1to 9 and using them to extract text boxes when the values change on value boxes

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply Geeky, that works on the first pair but I actually need to know how to do it for the rest of the array (not just the first pair)

Comment: If this worked for you added you any help...please consider accepting/upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is basic javascript.

```
var input=document.getElementsByClassName('sizebox');
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  if(input[i].value=='0.00'){
    input[i].style.background='#ff0000';
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cth254jh/1/